# Why can't I make .js file working with MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have very simple JS code to execute in my Model View:

View (I show main part where 'id' is included):

```
@model IEnumerable<XYZ.Models.DocumentsModel>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <tr> 
            <td>
               <select id="decisionList">
                    <option value="0" selected></option>
                    <option value="1">None</option>
                    <option value="2">Cancellation</option>
                    <option value="3">Payment date</option>
                    <option value="4">Manual date</option>
                    <option value="5">No date</option>
                </select>

            </td>
    </tr>

<script src="~/Content/Site.js"></script>
```

and JS:

```
var decisionList = document.getElementById("decisionList");

decisionList.addEventListener("change", function () {

    var selectedOptionIndex = decisionList.options[decisionList.selectedIndex].index;

    alert(selectedOptionIndex);  // no alert pops-up when changing the option on a list
    console.log(selectedOptionIndex); //no logs in a console at all

});
```

and JS doesn't work at all, my selected list is not reacting. I tried even other simpler codes in my JS file but also it doesn't work. I think I attached  properly. I also tried to add  in _Layout.cshtml but it also didn't help (I attached refs in head section of my _Layout so it's done properly). What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is your script file being loaded? Put an alert as the very first command of the script. If it doesn't trigger, your script isn't loaded.

Comment: I tried this and yes, it's being loaded and alert pops-up. Maybe sth wrong with my code? addEventListener is not working at all

Comment: Make sure `var decisionList` is not undefined, and there should be only one instance of `decisionList` in your HTML

Comment: Ok, got it. ```var decisionList = document.getElementById("decisionList");``` refers only to first selected list, I have about 100 rows, in each is this selected list. Using ```getElementsByClassName``` is better option?

Comment: Are you saying you have more than one element with the same `decisionList` id? If so, yeah, you shouldn't do that. An Id should be unique on the entire page. And if you are attaching a listener to it, you probably shouldn't do it with class, as every element with that class will have the same listener... probably not what you intend.

Comment: I did sth like this: ```document.querySelectorAll("#decisionList").forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener("change", function () {  ///some code ...``` So I added now addListener to all 100rows with field of id="decisionList". Is that ok?